# txtLatLong.split is not a function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I know this may be a duplicate question. I have googled it this issue but now able to find the solution for this, that's why i'm forced to ask this question here.

I am now working with the leaflet.js to get some map and google map as my base background layer.here is my script tags are

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet/leaflet.css"/>
    <script src="leaflet/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="leaflet/leaflet-src.js"></script>
    <script src="leaflet/geoGson.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./leaflet/locations/locationGeoGson.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyKey async defer></script>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/leaflet.gridlayer.googlemutant@latest/Leaflet.GoogleMutant.js'></script>
```

my script is

```
var newLatLong=getMyCustomLayLong(latLong);
function getMyCustomLayLong(txtLatLong){
    console.log("txtLatLong--"+txtLatLong.split(','));
    var cLong=txtLatLong.split(',')[0];
    var cLat=txtLatLong.split(',')[1];
    return cLat+','+cLat;
}
```

while i am trying to split the string with coma im getting the issue.Please help me t sort out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getMyCustomLayLong(txtLatLong){
    var f_txtLatLong=txtLatLong+'';
    var cLat=f_txtLatLong.split(',')[1];
    var cLong=f_txtLatLong.split(',')[0];
    return cLat+','+cLong;
}
```

This is works in my case.

Answer (score 0):

sample.split is not a function occurs when sample is **null or undefined**. 
We can't split a null value. So error throws. Try to print (console.log(txtLatLong ) ) txtLatLong in console to see its value.

Comment: txtLatLong--77.00234827943784,8.382997069681219 this is my console.

Comment: it seems that txtLatLong is not a string

Comment: Yes may be try to print console.log(typeof txtLatLong) in console. This will give you type of variable. if its not string convert to string before splitting

Comment: @Ashish451 the console is type--object

Comment: @Ashish451 it is a geo coordinates.

Comment: what i needs na i have to make this 77.00234827943784,8.382997069681219  to 8.382997069681219 ,77.00234827943784 this . please help me

Comment: I'll bet you're having an instance of [`L.LatLng`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#latlng). Just refer to its `.lat` and `.lng` properties, there should be no need of splitting any strings. And use the debug capabilities of your browser to inspect the values of the properties of your variables.